# Arrange $x,y,z$ in ascending order.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, roots

$c>1, c \in \mathbb{R}$

$x = \frac{\sqrt{c+2} - \sqrt{c+1}}{\sqrt{c} - \sqrt{c-1}}
     =  (\sqrt{c+2} - \sqrt{c+1})(\sqrt{c} + \sqrt{c-1})$

$y = \frac{\sqrt{c+2} - \sqrt{c+1}}{\sqrt{c + 1} - \sqrt{c}}
     = (\sqrt{c+2} - \sqrt{c+1})(\sqrt{c+1} + \sqrt{c})$

$z = \frac{\sqrt{c} - \sqrt{c-1}}{\sqrt{c+2} - \sqrt{c+1}}
     = (\sqrt{c} - \sqrt{c-1})(\sqrt{c+2} + \sqrt{c+1})$

It is pretty easy to prove that $x<y$. I have already done that. By experimental substitution, I have found out that $y<z$. But every time I try out prove this generically, I end up with LHS and RHS both looking terrible and yielding unwanted false results and conclusions like $ \sqrt x < 0$. Can someone please help me out in proving that $ y<z $??? Please. Even a definitive good hint is helpful.

Comment: perhaps[Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(%5Csqrt%7Bc%7D+-+%5Csqrt%7Bc-1%7D)(%5Csqrt%7Bc%2B2%7D+%2B+%5Csqrt%7Bc%2B1%7D)) can give you some insights.

Comment: Who downvoted? Please explain

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** One way to look at it is that $t\mapsto \sqrt t$ is concave, so successive secants have lower slope. Now can you relate $z,x$ by considering them as ratios of slopes?

Comment: I'm not that high up in math

Comment: I don't understand a word of your answer.